# TypeScript file not loaded or something

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, model-view-controller, typescript

I get an error in my console when I try to create a type script file from a partial view (MVC .NET) which is loaded by a rest call and appended to a div element.

I get: Uncaught ReferenceError: xyz is not defined.

in my partial view i have below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

    var model = @Html.GetJson(Model.x);
    var view = new xyz.ExceptionView();
    view.init();

  });
</script>
```

Edit: I added "@section scripts {}" around my script tag and then i get nothing in my console and no execution or logging from implementation

And I forgot to mention that my TypeScript file is not implementing anything. But here it is.
Is this not a correct way of using typescript?

```js
module xyz {

  export class ExceptionView {
    constructor() {
      debugger;
    }
    public init = (model: any): void => {
      debugger;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can't include or reference TypeScript directly in your HTML, I assume you have a script tag that includes the compiled JavaScript?  Does the JavaScript emitted from the TypeScript compilation look right?  Are you able to step through the final JavaScript code in the browser Web Developer Tools and see where the breakdown is occurring?

Comment: I must confess that I have not much knowledge about typescript. If I call the class from another typescript file I have the same problem. If I move my class to another existing type script file which is executed. I can call my moved class from my partial view.

I's like you say that the ts-file is not loaded. But i can't figure it out, they are all compiled when building project and I can se a reference to my not loaded ts-file in the project file.